# What was the process that created a plastic-looking material from the jam leftovers?

Tags: organic-chemistry, food-chemistry, plastics

I was making apricot jam using fresh apricots and gelling sugar. All went well except I burnt it. Some of the solid parts sank to the bottom and stuck there. After putting the good stuff in jars, I then soaked the pot.

About five hours later I went to scrub it and the whole bottom layer came free in a perfect circle. The under side is shiny — looks like plastic. The upper side is matt and almost furry. As it dries out it is curling up and is brittle.

What happened?

Comment: Classic sol-gel process. The overheating part dehydrated and became somewhat solid. After you soaked it in water afterwards, the soft and hard parts dried (and shrunk) differently, hence the curling up.

Comment: You've created a sucrose Frisbee.